# Ajax form always posting ViewModel with null values (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I submit the form, the ViewModel object in the controller action has null (or default) values for every field in the ViewModel. The ViewModel object itself isn't null, but all of its values are null or default (0 for the ints, 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM for the DateTimes, etc.).

After Googling this issue and seeing various suggestions, I've confirmed the following:

- The model state is valid.
- The names in the HTML markup for each field exactly match the name of the parameter in the ViewModel (NewItem.ID, NewItem.AnotherID, etc.).
- Changing the name of the parameter has no effect.

**Why aren't the ViewModel values posting correctly?**

Here's what I have:

**PaneViewModel**

```
public class PaneViewModel
{
    public ViewModel NewItem { get; set; }
    public DataTableViewModel DataTable { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
[Table("TableName")]
public class ViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DisplayName("AnotherID")]
    public int AnotherID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DisplayName("Some Date")]
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Another Date")]
    public DateTime AnotherDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("A Third Date")]
    public DateTime? AThirdDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddItem", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "add-item-section",
    LoadingElementId = "loading-image",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
}))
{
    <section id="add-item-section">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewItem.SomeDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewItem.AnotherDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewItem.AThirdDate)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewItem, "ViewModelEditorTemplate")
        </table>
    </section>
}
```

**View Model Editor Template**

```
@model ViewModel

<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeDate)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AnotherDate)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AThirdDate)</td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button></td>
</tr>

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AnotherID)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem(ViewModel item)
{
    // Breakpoint set here (code removed because it's irrelevant to this issue).
}
```

Comment: What is the `Model` of the parent object of the ViewModel? I think you are posting an object with a property of type ViewModel which may be confusing the Model Binding.

Comment: What is the model in the main view? Does it have a property named `NewItem`? It's obviously not typeof `ViewModel` so your form cannot post back to `ActionResult AddItem(ViewModel item)`. And the fact you have this in a table suggests its a collection, in which case you need to make numerous changes.

Comment: Just added the parent view model to the post details. I'm starting to think this is definitely the source of the problem.

Comment: Based on your edit, its not a collection so don't use a table (tables are for tabular data, not for layout!). You also need to rename your `EditorTemplate` to `/Views/.../ViewModel.cshtml` and just use `Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewItem)` And as an alternative to posting back to `PaneViewModel` as per the accepted answer, you could post back to `AddItem([Bind(Prefix="NewItem")]ViewModel item)` depending on what you are actually doing in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model binder is going to be attempting to match up those names `NewItem.ID` etc to the properties on the `ViewModel` class. Unfortunately the Model binder will not automatically know to drop the `NewItem` preface when binding to your object.

If you accept an object of type `ParentViewModel` (or whatever your initial Model is called), this should allow the Model binder to initialize the `ParentViewModel.NewItem` with the properties from the form correctly.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem(ParentViewModel item)
{
   ViewModel newItem = item.NewItem;// <-- bound using the name to properties mapping
}
```

If this is not desirable, you can always implement a custom Model Binder but that is probably overkill for this issue.

**EDIT**

Stephen also pointed out the alternative of using a [binding prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.prefix%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to explicitly tell the `ModelBinder` to expect `NewItem` before the properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem([Bind(Prefix="NewItem")]ViewModel item)
{
   //item should be bound using the properties correctly
}
```

Depending on your preference, either of these solutions should work for you.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. Making the change you suggested fixed it. I'm having some other problems now, but they're unrelated to this issue. Thanks!